# How do I get the key type hints for deep object?

Tags: typescript

```js
let Bob = {
    age: 24,
    name: 'bob',
    son: {
        foo: {
            age: 2,
        },
    },
}
const doSomething = (deepKey: any) => {
    // doSomething
}
// I want to have a type hint
doSomething('son.foo.age')
```

I want to have a literal type hint,
What do I do with deepKey to get a literal type hint ?

Comment: You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXK49W) using the answer to the linked question

Comment: Here's the other end of the deal, extracting the type of the value referenced by the deep-key: https://tsplay.dev/wOPj6N